# Importing a VHD into Parallels Desktop 6 on the Mac

Tags: virtual-machine, parallels, vhd

I've looked everywhere for this but can't find an answer, so:

I have a VHD image created for me by a client -- he installed Win7 on a machine and then used a tool from SysInternals to create a VHD which he shared with me and a colleague.

I can mount the VHD on my Mac using Parallels Mounter and see the contents, but I can't for the life of me see how to import the VHD to create a new Parallels VM from the VHD file. Parallels Transporter seems to want to create a VM from a live Windows box, which this isn't.

My colleague is able to use VirtualBox to create a VM from the VHD and I want to do the same using Parallels Desktop 6.

Any ideas?

Comment: more context: I can use VirtualBox on the mac and open the VHD, and it works, but I'd prefer to use Parallels with 256Mb VRAM -- VB seems to limit to 128Mb VRAM so can't use > 1600 x 1200 resolution.

Comment: I favourited this question, even though it should probably be over on SU.  :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Parallels is designed to import *virtual machines* rather than *virtual hard disks*. A VHD is just the hard disk, and doesn't specify anything about the machine.

So the answer is that you need to create a simple *virtual machine* that uses the VHD; Parallels can then import that (for Parallels 7 see ftt's answer below). To do that, create a simple UTF-8 text file with an extension `.vmc` containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<preferences>
<version type="string">2.0</version>
<hardware>
<pci_bus>
<ide_adapter>
<ide_controller id="0">
<location id="0">
<drive_type type="integer">1</drive_type>
<pathname>
<absolute type="string">/Users/Shared/VirtualPC/BaseDrive.vhd</absolute>
<relative type="string">BaseDrive.vhd</relative>
</pathname>
</location>
</ide_controller>
</ide_adapter>
</pci_bus>
</hardware>
</preferences>
```

Make sure you change the `.vhd` references above to the actual location of your VHD file.

The above code is from a recommendation by a Parallels team member [on Parallels forum](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=104420&mode=linear).

Comment: This worked for me, only thing is that Parallels expects the configuration file to have the extension `.vmc` (not `.mvc`)

Comment: Oh right, that's fixed now. I suppose it's because I use Spring MVC every day that I naturally typed `mvc` instead of `vmc`!

Answer (score 10):

For Parallels 7, try this:

```
$ /Library/Parallels/Parallels\ Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels\ VM\ Converter.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_convert your_disk_image.vhd
```

Found [here](http://joemaller.com/2896/ie6-ie7-and-ie8-compatibility-testing-with-microsoft-virtual-pcs/). The original post was about Parallels 6, so it should work there, too.

Comment: For Parallels 8: /Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_convert your_disk_image.vhd

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the HDD into an ISO - this can easily be done if you have a spare Win machine to run the conversion process. You will need software named [GImageX](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/gimagex/).

Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrks5uvhHGE) and also you can [read this](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=16125) if you like.

Good Luck, and please post your results.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Testing Internet Explorer on Mac with Microsoft VHD and Parallels 6

Download desired Win/IE combo from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

For extracting *.exe files on Mac use http://www.unrarx.com/

cd Download

/Library/Parallels//Parallels\ Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels\ VM\ Converter.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_convert "Windows 7.vhd"

Run Parallels. Login with password: Password1

http://www.ericmichaelstone.com/?p=5962

Comment: The key here is to unzip the exe file, NOT to run the exe file (which also extracts it)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads. There are parallels-specific downloads, along with many other formats.